# Getting the difference from 2 SELECTs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the difference from two columns in two different tables.
There is no keys so I can't do a join (I think).

I have the following 2 statements:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(dbo.MonitorIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') AS Time, 
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData.gridP AS MonitorP 
FROM 
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData

SELECT 
    FORMAT(dbo.InverterIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') AS Time, 
    dbo.InverterIntervalData.gridP AS InverterP 
FROM 
    dbo.InverterIntervalData
```

All I need is to return the difference between the `MonitorP` and `InverterP` along with the `Time`.

I have tried

```
SELECT
    (SELECT 
         FORMAT(dbo.InverterIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') AS Time, 
         dbo.InverterIntervalData.gridP AS InverterP 
     FROM dbo.InverterIntervalData) -
    (SELECT 
         FORMAT(dbo.MonitorIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') AS Time, 
         dbo.MonitorIntervalData.gridP AS MonitorP 
     FROM dbo.MonitorIntervalData) AS Difference
```

but that does not work.

How would I got about this one?

UPDATE:
As per help i ended up with this

```
SELECT 
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData.timestamp as time,
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData.gridP AS MonitorP,
    dbo.InverterIntervalData.timestamp, 
    dbo.InverterIntervalData.gridP AS InverterP ,
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData.gridP - dbo.InverterIntervalData.gridP as Difference
FROM 
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData inner join dbo.InverterIntervalData
    ON FORMAT(dbo.MonitorIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') = FORMAT(dbo.InverterIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm')
    ORDER BY timestamp
```

Thanks

Comment: To compare the values in the two tables there needs to be some sort of key/join relationship.  Can you tell us what that might be?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: What do you mean by difference? Do you mean the difference of values (e.g. 5-3=2) or the difference of sets (e.g. {2,3,4} - {2,3} = {4})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(dbo.MonitorIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') AS MTime, 
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData.gridP AS MonitorP ,
    FORMAT(dbo.InverterIntervalData.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') AS ITime, 
    dbo.InverterIntervalData.gridP AS InverterP ,
    DATEDIFF( month, dbo.MonitorIntervalData.timestamp, dbo.InverterIntervalData.timestamp) as Difference
FROM 
    dbo.MonitorIntervalData 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.InverterIntervalData ON dbo.InverterIntervalData.gridP = dbo.MonitorIntervalData.gridP
```

Here I consider that both of your records are inter related with `gridP`.

For `DATEDIFF` , you may find this link for more info [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: So close I could work the rest out my self:) I added the final code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First select the dates and put them in a separated variables then use 'DATEDIFF' to get the result.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate );
```

> The following lists all valid names for 'datepart' arguments:
>   { year,
>   quarter,
>   month,
>   dayofyear,
>   day,
>   week,
>   hour,
>   minute,
>   second }

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of table aliases?

```
SELECT mi.timestamp as time,
       mi.gridP AS MonitorP,
       ii.timestamp, 
       ii.gridP AS InverterP ,
       (mi.gridP - ii.gridP) as Difference
FROM dbo.MonitorIntervalData mi INNER JOIN 
     dbo.InverterIntervalData ii
    ON FORMAT(mi.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm') = FORMAT(ii.timestamp, 'dd-MM.yyyy HH:mm')
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Your query is just really hard to follow.

This is reasonable logic, but you will lose values if they do not match between the tables.  You might want to consider a `FULL JOIN` instead.